# Unable to fire a "change" event - please provide a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing a unit test case using jest and react testing library for event invoked by change in dropdown options in React.
The code for Component is as follows:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("fruit")

  function selectionChange(params) {
    console.log(params)
    setValue(params)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <select data-test-id="Oshop" onChange={(e) => selectionChange(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>

          <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>

          <option value="meat">Meat</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the code for unit test is as follows:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';



test('testing onchange event for oshop', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const dropdElement = screen.queryByTestId("Oshop")
  fireEvent.change(dropdElement,{target:{value:"meat"}})
  expect(dropdElement.value).toBe("meat")
});
```

First when I was using getTestById then I was getting error as

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="Oshop"]

Then again I tried with queryByTestId and I started getting error as

> Unable to fire a "change" event - please provide a DOM element.

Comment: Note you don't actually need the test ID here, you can select it by _role_ - https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority. It should have a label too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `data-testid`, **not** `data-test-id`, see [ByTestId](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/)

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState()
  function selectionChange(value) {
    console.log(value)
    setSelectedValue(value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={selectedValue} data-testid="Oshop" onChange={(e) => selectionChange(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
        <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
        <option value="meat">Meat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import App from './App';

test('testing onchange event for oshop', (done) => {
  render(<App />);
  const dropdElement = screen.queryByTestId("Oshop");
  expect(dropdElement).toHaveValue(undefined);
  if (!dropdElement) return done('select element not found');
  fireEvent.change(dropdElement, { target: { value: "meat" } });
  expect(screen.getByTestId('Oshop')).toHaveValue('meat');
  done();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76117012/App.test.tsx (6.713 s)
  ✓ testing onchange event for oshop (36 ms)

  console.log
    meat

      at selectionChange (stackoverflow/76117012/App.tsx:6:13)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 App.tsx  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.013 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: Thanks, though it is a minor change, I am keeping the answer for other's reference as I personally didn't find much on the error heading and your points are also marked.